# Adding caption to a prooftree

Tags: captions, bussproofs

I am trying to add a caption to a prooftree generated using bussproofs **without** using the figure environment. The reason I am trying to do this is because the proof is located in a theorem environment and I've read that the two (figure and theorem) don't work very well together. Can anyone please suggest a way to resolve this?

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  \begin{prooftree}
    \AxiomC{foo}
    \LeftLabel{bar}
    \RightLabel{baz}
    \UnaryInfC{Yo!}
    \singleLine
  \end{prooftree}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\captionof{figure}{ <caption text>}`? for it you need to load `caption` package or `capt-of` in preamble.

Comment: I have tried using this but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: What do you mean? It produces output. Depending on where you place the `\captionof` command, the formatting will differ.  Perhaps edit your question to show what you did with caption and explain what doesn't work about it.

Comment: Oh yes this does actually work. I was miss guided by a page break showing the apparently wrong result. Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments